# Hide Show Content Javascript WordPress posts

Tags: javascript, wordpress, posts

So I'm trying to make an list op posts on Wordpress, with the content hidden until you click on it, when you click on a other post, it will hide the open one, and show the new one. I came up with this script:

```
    var activePlayer = null
function setActivePlayer(newActivePlayer) {
  if (activePlayer) {
    activePlayer.classList.remove(“EpisodeShow”);
    activePlayer.classList.add(“EpisodeSHide”);
  }
  activePlayer = newActivePlayer;
  if (newActivePlayer) {
    newActivePlayer.classList.remove(“EpisodeSHide”);
    newActivePlayer.classList.add(“EpisodeShow”);
  }
}
```

Which is in the WordPress post loop like this

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <header class="all-episodes">
        <div onclick="{ setActivePlayer(event.element)};" class="row" id="episode-<?php echo get_the_ID();?>"><p class="episode-item">
                <?php the_title(); ?>&nbsp;-&nbsp;
                <?php echo get_the_date('d/m/Y'); ?>&nbsp;-&nbsp;
                <?php echo strip_tags (get_the_term_list( get_the_ID(), 'shows', "",", " ));?>&nbsp;-&nbsp;
                <?php echo strip_tags (get_the_term_list( get_the_ID(), 'genres', "",", " ));?>
            </p>
        </div> 
    </header><!-- .entry-header -->
    <div class="episode-content EpisodeHide" id=" episode-content-<?php echo get_the_ID();?>">
        <?php
        the_content(
            sprintf(
                wp_kses(
                    /* translators: %s: Post title. Only visible to screen readers. */
                    __( 'Continue reading<span class="screen-reader-text"> "%s"</span>', 'twentynineteen' ),
                    array(
                        'span' => array(
                            'class' => array(),
                        ),
                    )
                ),
                get_the_title()
            )
        );

        wp_link_pages(
            array(
                'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . __( 'Pages:', 'twentynineteen' ),
                'after'  => '</div>',
            )
        );
        ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-content -->

    <footer class="entry-footer">
    </footer><!-- .entry-footer -->
</article>
```

Which get the styles from a loaded stylesheet which is as simple as this:

```
.EpisodeHide {
    display: none;
}

.EpisodeShow {
    display: block;
}
```

Now I receive this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: setActivePlayer is not defined
    at HTMLDivElement.onclick ((index):103)
```

the line changes to the line where the posts onclick is on

```
<div onclick="{setActivePlayer(event.element)};" class="row" id="episode-6"><p class="episode-item">
```

Any suggestions?

It would help me a lot!!!
Thanks in advance

Comment: where and how do you place place your js code ? Can you post your file?

Comment: @AngelDeykov I added it between my <head> tags. and of course between <script> tags as well!

Comment: try to put in in a file and include it through functions->wp_enqueue_script()

Comment: I changed the "..." in the Javascript to '...' and changed the onclick to onclick="{ setActivePlayer(event.srcElement)};". Now the code works, but interacts with the wrong content. It puts the Classes on <p class="episode-item"> rather than the DIV with class "episode-content". Any idea's on how to address this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out!

For the people who want to know how:

 **Javascript**

```
        var activePlayer = null
    function setActivePlayer(newActivePlayerID) {
        var newActivePlayer = document.getElementById(newActivePlayerID);

        if (activePlayer) {
            activePlayer.classList.remove('EpisodeShow');
            activePlayer.classList.add('EpisodeHide');
        }
        activePlayer = newActivePlayer;
        if (newActivePlayer) {
            newActivePlayer.classList.remove('EpisodeHide');
            newActivePlayer.classList.add('EpisodeShow');
        }
    }
```

**Post Loop Code**

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <header class="all-episodes">
        <div onclick="{ setActivePlayer('episode-content-<?php echo get_the_ID();?>')};" class="row" id="episode-<?php echo get_the_ID();?>"><p class="episode-item">
                <?php the_title(); ?>&nbsp;-&nbsp;
                <?php echo get_the_date('d/m/Y'); ?>&nbsp;-&nbsp;
                <?php echo strip_tags (get_the_term_list( get_the_ID(), 'shows', "",", " ));?>&nbsp;-&nbsp;
                <?php echo strip_tags (get_the_term_list( get_the_ID(), 'genres', "",", " ));?>
            </p>
        </div> 
    </header><!-- .entry-header -->
    <div class="episode-content EpisodeHide" id="episode-content-<?php echo get_the_ID();?>">
        <?php
        the_content(
            sprintf(
                wp_kses(
                    /* translators: %s: Post title. Only visible to screen readers. */
                    __( 'Continue reading<span class="screen-reader-text"> "%s"</span>', 'twentynineteen' ),
                    array(
                        'span' => array(
                            'class' => array(),
                        ),
                    )
                ),
                get_the_title()
            )
        );

        wp_link_pages(
            array(
                'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . __( 'Pages:', 'twentynineteen' ),
                'after'  => '</div>',
            )
        );
        ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-content -->

    <footer class="entry-footer">
    </footer><!-- .entry-footer -->
</article>
```

The Style sheet is the same!
Works like a charm :)